# Как обнулять последующий select при смене значения в текущем?

Tags: javascript

Есть несколько select. Каждый последующий отображается при наличии значения в предыдущем. Логично, что если в select выше значения изменилось, то обнулять последующий. Но, как это сделать?

Я пытался через `reset()` - в моём случае не подходит. Обнуляется вся форма.
В примере последующий select просто скрывается, но когда их много этот вариант не работает, нужно именно обнулять при смене значения в верхнем select.

```js
function selectChange() {
  let oneQuestion = document.getElementById('one-question');
  let twoQuestion = document.getElementById('two-question');
  let threeQuestion = document.getElementById('three-question');
  let fourQuestion = document.getElementById('four-question');

  if (oneQuestion.value === 'yes') {
    threeQuestion.classList.remove('d-n');
    fourQuestion.classList.remove('d-n');
  } else if (oneQuestion.value === 'no') {
    threeQuestion.classList.add('d-n');
    fourQuestion.classList.add('d-n');

    twoQuestion.classList.remove('d-n');
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Любите есть на ночь?</p>
  <select id="one-question" onchange="selectChange()">
    <option value="none">Выберите значение</option>
    <option value="yes">Да</option>
    <option value="no">Нет</option>
  </select>

  <p class="d-n" id="two-question">Почему?</p>

  <p class="d-n" id="three-question">Какую еду?</p>
  <select id="four-question" class="d-n" onchange="selectChange()">
    <option>Выберите значение</option>
    <option>Пирожки</option>
    <option>Сладости</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Вы можете сложить все селекты, которые связаны между собой, в массив в той последовательности, в которой они у вас появляются на странице. При изменении какого-то из них вы просто ставите значения по умолчанию в тех, которые идут после него в этом массиве. Самый простой вариант

Answer (score 0):

Решение получилось таким образом:

```
var selects = document.getElementsByClassName('select-item');

Array.from(selects).forEach((el, i) => {
    el.onchange = (e) => {
      if (e.target.value == 'Выберите значение') {
         for (let j = i+1; j < selects.length; j++) {
           selects[j].selectedIndex = 0;
           selects[j].parentElement.classList.remove('shown');
         }
       } else {
         if (selects[i+1] !== undefined) {            selects[i+1].parentElement.classList.add('shown');
         }
         for (let j = i+1; j < selects.length; j++) {
           selects[j].selectedIndex = 0;
         }
       }         
    }
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]